# knockout checkbinding get last (de)selected element

Tags: typescript, checkbox, knockout.js, binding

I have show or hide div's that are selected in my settings box. For this i have to use a knockout checked binding but this only returns me an array of selected elements but i need the last changed element an then need to know if it's selected or not. This to prevent unnecessary looping.

the index.cshtml:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox-category" name="checkbox" data-bind="attr: {id: 'checkbox' + category.id }, checked: $root.enabledCategories, checkedValue: category" checked />
```

the typescript classe:

```
 enabledCategories: KnockoutObservableArray<Category>;

        this.enabledCategories = ko.observableArray([]);

        this.enabledCategories(this.categories());
this.enabledCategories.subscribe(function (val) {

            console.log(val);              

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing it a little wrong... the `checked` binding is supposed to be bound to a boolean value, you have it bound to an `ObservableArray`.

If you need to know which checkbox was clicked and if it is checked or not, you might want to try the `click` binding:

`click: $root.CateoryClicked.bind($data)`

or something like that...

then in your view model you have this:

```
this.CateoryClicked = function(item) {
    if (item.IsSelected){
       //do what you need to do
    } else {
       item.IsSelected = true;
       //do what you need to do
    }
}
```

here the item should be the object (`category`) that is bound to the checkbox. I don't know how you have all that set up, but I'm assuming here that you have an IsSelected property on that object.